# How to handle categorical legends with too many entries to match a fixed chart height?

Tags: legend, vega-lite

I am using a Vega-Lite chart template (using vega-embed) on a dashboard containing filters to control various aspects of the data being displayed. The Chart is contained within a widget of defined size and uses `""autosize": {"type": "fit", "contains": "padding"}` to control the chart sizing.

One of the charts is causing me some issues - a stacked bar chart displaying some counts through time grouped by company. In a few instances, there are too many companies within the data being brought into the dashboard, resulting in the legend being cut off. E.G. [only ~25 of the 50+ legend entries showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmkkE.png)

Is there some way of making this legend more useful? I am using tooltips which goes some way, but short of just disabling the legend (rejected by the product manager) I'm stumped about how to proceed. I have tried to put together some conditional logic to make it so that if distinct count >= 25 then `"legend": {"columns": 2}`, but not had any luck in making this work.

Does anyone have any ideas on a general solution that will work for both instances of 25+ legend entries and 5? Having the legend be scroll-able would be the ideal solution, likewise having a cap on the number of legend entries (rest binned into `other`) are also viable alternatives I have thought of but don't know how to do in vega-lite.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm not a web developer, just an analyst who's picked up the job of writing vega-lite specs so apologies for the lack of technical detail on how it's deployed!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a number of columns in the `legend` argument of the relevant encoding. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

np.random.seed(4567)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.randn(100),
    'y': np.random.randn(100),
    'category': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 100)
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color=alt.Color('category', legend=alt.Legend(columns=3))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks responding. This post seemingly got tagged as Python by mistake, I have edited that to clarify that my question relates to Vega-Lite.

Comment: OK. In Vega-Lite, you can use ``{'legend': {'columns': 3}}`` within the Color encoding to get the same effect.